# Sort Array for a table with 3 columns

Tags: java

I have a list of elements and want to display the list like:

```
ADG
BEH
CFI
```

(The table gets filled from top left to bottom right)

My code works if I remove the "I" from the list... but obviously I'd like to make it work for every case:

```
    List<String> beanz = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I");
    String[] sortedBeanz = new String[beanz.size()];

    int i = 0;
    while (i < beanz.size()) {

        int shift = (i * 3) / beanz.size();
        int pos = ((i * 3) - beanz.size() * shift);

        System.out.println(pos + " " + beanz.get(i));
        sortedBeanz[pos] = beanz.get(i);
        i++;
    }
```

I'm stuck and can't figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: *Unrelated:* Haven't you learned about the `for` loop yet?

Comment: @LutzHorn Look at code again. There is no input needed.

Comment: Have you learned about the modulus operator (`%`)? It would help with your code if you use it.

Comment: Did you tried to debug?

Comment: But, your example is already sorted, your goal is to pick every third element and proceed to some action (for example adding the element to `StringBuilder`. By *the third* I didn't literally meant the third! Use the mod operator as @Andreas suggested.

Comment: @user489872 Please check my dynamic solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50016537/2735286 for cubes and 3 columns in this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple, but scalable solution which will create sorted cubes of characters according to the size of the input. It will produce cubes with 3 x 3 or 4 x 4, etc characters depending on the size of the input.

It is an elastic solution:

```
public static void sortSizeable(List<String> beanz) {
    Collections.sort(beanz);
    int cols = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(beanz.size()));
    String[][] sortedBeanz = new String[cols][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < beanz.size(); i++) {
        int row = i / cols;
        int col = i % cols;
        sortedBeanz[col][row] = beanz.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(sortedBeanz)
            .map(array -> Arrays.stream(array).collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, s) -> sb.append(s == null ? "=" : s).append(" "), (sb, s) -> {} ))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\r\n")));
}
```

Here are is a test case with corresponding output below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    sortSizeable(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P"));
    System.out.println();
    sortSizeable(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"));
    System.out.println();
    sortSizeable(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
    System.out.println();
    sortSizeable(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"));
    System.out.println();
    sortSizeable(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R"));
}
```

This will print out the following cubes or sorted characters:

```
A E I M 
B F J N 
C G K O 
D H L P 

A D G 
B E H 
C F = 

A C 
B D 

A D G 
B E H 
C F I 

A F K P = 
B G L Q = 
C H M R = 
D I N = = 
E J O = =
```

**Update**

If you want an elastic solution for 3 rows only here is the solution:

```
public static void sortSizeable2(List<String> beanz) {
    Collections.sort(beanz);
    final int cols = 3; // Number of columns
    int rows = (int) Math.ceil(beanz.size() / (cols * 1.0));
    String[][] sortedBeanz = new String[rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < beanz.size(); i++) {
        int row = i / rows;
        int col = i % rows;
        sortedBeanz[col][row] = beanz.get(i);
    }
    printOut(sortedBeanz);
}
```

If you run this test on this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    sortSizeable2(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P"));
    System.out.println();
    sortSizeable2(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"));
    System.out.println();
    sortSizeable2(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
    System.out.println();
    sortSizeable2(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"));
    System.out.println();
    sortSizeable2(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R"));
}
```

You will see this:

```
A G M 
B H N 
C I O 
D J P 
E K = 
F L = 

A D G 
B E H 
C F = 

A C = 
B D = 

A D G 
B E H 
C F I 

A G M 
B H N 
C I O 
D J P 
E K Q 
F L R
```

Comment: I've up voted, but the number of columns should be exactly 3, no matter how large is the input. Also, I'd use `Collections.sort` in the `sortSizeable` method, just in case if the input isn't already sorted.

Comment: @zlakad You are right. The question is not asking about cubes. I did not get this quite right. I have added the sort. Thank you.

Comment: @zlakad I have now added a solution for a pre-defined number of columns in the update

Comment: That's the right answer! Although, I'm not really sure in the third example (the question itself isn't precise enough). Should it be as you answered, or maybe `ACB` `D==`. However, I think you did a good job, and if OP isn't satisfied, he should do his own task by himself...

Comment: @zlakad Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome, friend. My up vote still standing. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

A slick Java 8 approach to this:

```
List<String> beanz = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I");
String in = String.join("", beanz);
System.out.println(in.replaceAll("(.)..", "$1"));
System.out.println(in.replaceAll(".(.).", "$1"));
System.out.println(in.replaceAll("..(.)", "$1"));

ADG
BEH
CFI
```

### Demo

Comment: I need the elements in an array because another application is processing the values

Comment: @user489872, it is not what you asked! You said *I want to display*!

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use loops

```
List<String> beanz = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I");
for (int i = 0; i < beanz.size()/3; i++){
    for (int j = i; j < beanz.size(); j += 3){
        System.out.print(beanz.get(j));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

The output is as you want

```
ADG
BEH
CFI
```

If you want 3 columns view -

```
List<String> beanz = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L");
int rows = beanz.size()/3;
for (int i = 0; i < beanz.size()/3; i++){
    for (int j = i; j < beanz.size(); j += rows){
        System.out.print(beanz.get(j));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Ther output is

```
AEI
BFJ
CGK
DHL
```

Comment: If I add one letter it becomes a 4 column layout

Comment: and you want 3 col layout? How it will be look for example for 12 letters?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> beanz = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I","J","K");
    String[] sortedBeanz = new String[beanz.size()];
    int column = 3; 
    int l = beanz.size();
    l = l - (l % column);
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i = i+column)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            sortedBeanz[i+j] = beanz.get(i+j);
            System.out.print(sortedBeanz[i+j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

if it does not fit, the last will be cut out

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modulus function to shift and adjust the position, something like this,

```
    int i = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    int shift =3;
    while (i < beanz.size()) {
        if (i%shift  == 0) {
            pos= i/shift;
        }
        sortedBeanz[pos] = beanz.get(i);
        System.out.println(pos+ " " + beanz.get(i));
        pos+=shift;
        i++;
    }
```